# jquery multiple selector with a this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I see, from to time, this kind of jquery selector, which I don't really understand. What does `this` do in it:

```
$('.myClass', this).someFn();
```

Can someone explain to me, please?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: It is the "context", a optional parameter. The "default context" is the whole document. In your exemple the context is "this" (a pointer to the local DOM element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That searches for child elements with a class of `myClass` in the context of whatever `this` is and then calls `someFn();`

It would give you the same results as writing `$(this).find(".myClass").someFn();` but is not as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are trying to select `.myClass` inside just `this`

Answer (score 0):

The "this" keyword is something that is only meaningful inside a method of an object.  It will mean something different -- or nothing at all -- depending on where you're calling this code from.

If you're calling it from inside an object (usually an HTML element), the object will be added to the selector that is passed to jQuery.